# How to create a Secure QRCode in Swift that can be only scan by a single app?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, cryptoswift, apple-cryptokit

How to create a Secure QRCode in Swift that can be only scan by a single app? Can we encrypt and decrypt the QRCode values using sha56?

Comment: SHA256 is a message digest, you can't encrypt/decrypt anything using that algorithm.

Comment: For encryption, look for AES or Salsa (or other ciphers cutently considered as secure)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.